# Keep the content of SSH sessions

Tags: 20.04, ssh, gnu-screen

Let's say I have this python script on my VPS:

```
# test.py
import time

while True:
    print('tick...')
    time.sleep(10)
```

If I log into my VPS using SSH and run this script, I can see `tick...` messages appearing in the console. But if I log out and log in again, everything is gone. I can see using `htop` that the python script is still running, just not printing anything into my new SSH session.

Is there any way I can recover the last SSH session, so I can see the results of my script again?

I tried the `screen` tool (`screen -S test` -> `python test.py`), but after re-connecting to SSH, when I try to go to my screen session (`screen - S test`) it only prints `[screen is terminating]`.

Comment: Running `screen -S test` multiple times will result in multiple sessions, see `screen -ls` to list all sessions.

Comment: @pLumo He did not run `screen -S test` the second time, but `screen - S test` (space between minus and S). This command is incorrect and screen is immediately returning.

Comment: @raj Sorry, it was typo in my post. My bad. Actually I didn't put the space between `-` and `S` when writing to the terminal.

Comment: @nanuqcz However, the command with space actually makes the screen terminate right away :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `screen - S test` is incorrect. If you want to re-attach to your detached screen session called "test", you should use the command

```
screen -R test
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it :-) I'll just summarize, how it is working for me now:  
Connect to SSH → `screen -S test` → `python test.py` → Re-connect to SSH → `screen -r test` → I can see the script output :-)